# Error: Transport already attached: file, assign a different name at Logger.add

Tags: node.js, express

I prepared logs to my functions and inserting the logs in a file called project.log. Here I had 2 files and I want to store the logs of 2 files in one file i.e project.log but when I run the code I get an error

```
Transport already attached: file, assign a different name
at Logger.add (/var/www/html/forum/server/node_modules/winston/lib/winston/logger.js:481:11)
```

I am confused with this,can anyone suggest me help.
My file1.js

```
log = require('../../../config/logs.js').config;
winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'project.log' });
exports.insertcategory = function (req, res) {
  if (log.status == 1) {
    winston.log('info', 'Entered insertcategory')
  }
  var obj = req.body;
  if (Object.keys(obj).length === 0) {
    if (log.status == 1) {
      winston.log('error', 'Input parameters are not reached');
    }
  }
```

My file2.js,

```
log = require('../../../config/logs.js').config;
//  winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'praoject.log'});
/* ------ Inserting topics ------ */
exports.inserttopic = function (req, res) {
  if (log.status == 1) {
    winston.log('info', 'Entered insertcategory')
  }
  var obj = req.body;
  if (Object.keys(obj).length === 0) {
    if (log.status == 1) {
      winston.log('error', 'Input parameters are not reached');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything I am finding says to add the name parameter to the to the transport object like below. However, thought the error no longer shows, only one file is being written to for me. Let me know if this works:

```
winston.configure({
transports: [
    new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: 'logs/info.log', name: 'file.info', level: 'info'}),
    new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: 'logs/warn.log', name: 'file.error', level: 'error'})
]
});
```